# How to sculpt through/ignore "backface culling?"

Tags: modeling, sculpting

I'm basically creating a sort of dug out bunker and everything is going great so far.. However - I've started to sculpt the walls and, due to clipping, I've enabled backface culling so that I don't have to be zoomed in so close all of the time.

However I can't seem to find a way to tell the brush to ignore the faces that I am seeing through. It simply sculpts on those faces and not the faces that I actually want to sculpt on.

I've thought about separating the walls up/hiding them but then that would disrupt the flow of topology.

Is there anything that I can do to ensure that Blender literally ignores the backfaces when trying to sculpt on the faces I want to?

Thanks!

Comment: *3D view header > Brush > Front Faces Only* will at least keep brush strokes from affecting the culled faces. Also, **Alt B** can be used to create a clipping border which could be useful for something like this.

Comment: I had tried the front faces option prior to asking here and it still does it sadly

Comment: That's why I suggested the clipping border. Have you tried that?